# Solving an equation in $\mathbb N$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

I am trying to solve the equation $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{3}{5}.$$
I have made the following progress:
1) $x, y z$ have to be larger than $1$
2) only one of x, y, z can be $2$; rest should be larger
3) WLOG I have assummed $2\leqslant x\leqslant y\leqslant z$.  Knowing this, $x$ has to be smaller than $5$. How to find $y$ and $z$ for all cases of $x \in\{2, 3, 4, 5\}$ to be sure that I am finding all cases?
Thanks.

Comment: Calculate $\frac{3}{5}-\frac{1}{x}$ in each case and repeat your argument with two fractions.

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  I understand the solution, just seems like a lot of trial and error after that.

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  I understand the solution.  It seems like a lot of trial and error, though.  Is there a more "elegant" approach to this than mine?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exhaustive list. But it is at least a partial solution.

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{3}{5}.$$

We know that $\dfrac{1}{ab}=\dfrac{1}{a(a+b)} + \dfrac{1}{b(a+b)}$

### Let $x=2$ and you get $\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{10}.$

We can use $a=2$ and $b=5$ to get

$$\frac{3}{5} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{14}+\frac{1}{35}.$$

### Let $x=3$ and you get $\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{4}{15}.$

We consider $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Then 
$\dfrac{1}{ag}+\dfrac{1}{bg}=\dfrac{a+b}{abg}=\dfrac{4}{15}$.
It seems $a=1$, $b=3$, and $g=5$ will work. We get

$$\frac{3}{5} = \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{15}.$$

### Let $x=4$ and you get $\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{7}{20}.$

We consider $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Then 
$\dfrac{1}{ag}+\dfrac{1}{bg}=\dfrac{a+b}{abg}=\dfrac{7}{20}$.
No solution there. Next we try
$\dfrac{1}{ag}+\dfrac{1}{bg}=\dfrac{a+b}{abg}=\dfrac{14}{40}$.
Then $(a,b,g)=(4,10,1)$ gives us

$$\frac{3}{5} = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{10}.$$

### Let $x=5$ and you get $\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{2}{5}.$

We consider $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Then 
$\dfrac{1}{ag}+\dfrac{1}{bg}=\dfrac{a+b}{abg}=\dfrac{2}{5}$.
Then $(a,b,g)=(1,1,5)$ gives us

$$\frac{3}{5} = \frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The same sort of argument you have made can be repeated.  Clearly if $x=5$ you must have $y=z=5$.  If $x=4$ you have $\frac 1y+\frac 1z=\frac 7{20}$ or $20(y+z)=7yz$ and $\frac 1y \ge \frac 7{40}$ so $y \in \{4,5\}$  We get $(4,5,10)$ as the only  solution.  If $x=3, \frac 1y+\frac 1z=\frac 4{15}$ and $y \in \{3,4,5,6,7\}$.  There are not too many cases to try.  A spreadsheet and copy down can ease the burden.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this does resort to trial and error: I think there are some other numerical methods but I can't remember them off the top of my head. We can assume $x\le y\le z$.

We have $$\frac1y< \frac3{5}-\frac1x \le \frac2y$$

$$\iff \frac{5x}{3x-5}<y\le \frac{10x}{3x-5}$$

Trial and error:

1. $x=y=2 \Rightarrow z=\frac1{\frac3{5}-\frac12-\frac12}=-\frac5{2}$ so this doesn't work.

...

$n.$ $\quad x=3,y=4...,z=60$ works. etc...

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{3}{5}$

Above equation has parametric solution given below:

$(x,y,z) = (4p,12p,5pk)$

Where $p=(5k+3)/(9k)$

For $k=2$, we get:

$(x,y,z)= ((26/9),(78/9),(65/9))$